# test missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

Trying to write what should be a straightforward RSpec test and have set up my create action to render JSON like the following:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CommentsController do

  let(:valid_attributes) do
    {
        title: 'First Comment', comment_text: 'LoremIpsum', commentable_id: 1,
        user_id: 1, entered_by: 'john', last_updated_by: 'doe'
    }
  end

  context 'JSON' do
    describe 'POST create' do
      describe 'with valid params' do
        it 'creates a new Comment' do
          json = {:format => 'json', :comment => valid_attributes}
          post :create, json
        end

        it 'assigns a newly created comment as @comment' do
          json = {:format => 'json', :comment => valid_attributes}
          post :create, json
          assigns(:comment).should be_a(Comment)
          assigns(:comment).should be_persisted
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However I am getting the following output:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template comments/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
```

Comment: Not quite sure about the root cause of your specific problem, but I recommend a look at the ActiveModelSerializers gem. It takes care of all that you're trying to accomplish above, and efficiently. Alternatives are Rabl (not advised) and JBuilder (new, and improved serialization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed the `else` part when `@commentable` is nil. this will try rendering the default template!

to clarify:

this is what was posted initially:

```
  def create
    if @commentable
      @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
      if @comment.save
        render json: @comment, status: :created
      else
        render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end
  end
```

in the case where `@commentable` is `nil` there is nothing that tells rails what to render, so it will try to render the default template for the create action. this is where `Missing template comments/create` comes from.

what i mean with the `else` part is this:

```
  def create
    if @commentable
      [...]
    else
      head 404
    end
  end
```

Comment: i do not understand your update... do you want to do a `render nothing: true` ?

Comment: What do you mean I missed the `else` part when `@commentable` is nil? which is why i then thought maybe I missed the `else` after the first `if`. But what did you mean by this